# Bootstrap3 Navbar - Border-Bottom length on links

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Just asked a similar questions but turned out i overlooked where i placed the tag. It was fixed but created another issue.

Added a style to the hover of the links whereby a border appears upon hover:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
    padding: 5px;
    color: white;
    border-bottom: #16b2d9 solid 3px;
}
```

All works fine however, is there a way to make the border length adjust depending on the length of the text?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an underline instead of a bottom border:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
    padding: 5px;
    color: black;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gratiafide/goLk6gcf/3/